# Struts 2.0 not working in IE

Tags: jquery, struts2

I have website that uses Struts 2.0 with AJAX tags..the website is
displaying/working fine in Mozilla Firefox but when i tried to view it in
Internet Explorer it is not working for certain tags and also not supporting json..
I dont know how to solve it..I need to make my application browser independent..is there difference in coding with Struts 2 in IE and Mozilla? How can I solve this problem?

and also when i tried to use it in windows struts2 buttons and tab are not working.. but its working correct in linux.. How to solve this..

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: "it is not working for certain tags and also not supporting json" - giving more detail about these facts will be of great benefit for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is related to Struts 2.0, as it is a server side technology.  It's custom tags are translated at server side.  It is however possible that the Ajax/Javascript features you are using, are non IE compliant.

Comment: You may have to change the Javascript to be compatible with IE.  Try debugging which calls are failing exactly.

Answer (score 0):

For Which tags its not working describe it but i guess what Sid has suggested is rigth since i have few projects with Struts2.x and all are working fine in all Browsers

Comment: that's not related to Struts2.x and follow what Sid has recommend and you have to debug only. i am sure there is some property which is being supported in Mozilla but not in IE.this is a very common case when working on cross browser functionality